# JavaFX. Создание HUD следующего за камерой

Tags: javafx, разработка-игр, камера

Пишу игру. По нажатию на стрелки двигается персонаж,а вместе с ним камера. Нужно реализовать HUD, представляющий из себя Pane внизу окна, который содержит в себе некоторые элементы. Каким образом это реализовать так, чтобы элемент был "прикреплен" к камере? (привожу пример)

[image: Пример - игра Dota 2]

Comment: Имеется ввиду, что элемент, расположенный на панели по мере движения должен уходить из вида? (если есть возможность, то как нибудь подробнее опишите вопрос. Может быть даже с картинками). Или приложите пример кода, с описанием как есть и как должно быть.

Comment: @АлександрСавостьянов нет, элемент, как раз таки, должен быть "прикреплен" к камере, чтобы вне зависимости от её глобального положения, он всегда оставался на одном месте относительно неё.

Comment: Ну разве можно не помочь фанату доты) Вот нагуглил для вас [страничку](https://docs.oracle.com/javafx/8/3d_graphics/subscene.htm). Между прочим официальная документация, и конкретно по вашей теме (не забывайте сначала поискать самостоятельно)

Comment: @АлександрСавостьянов большое спасибо! Это именно то,что нужно!